# Adding padding to fitBounds in leaflet for R

Tags: r

I want to create a pipeline in R that builds a map using leaflet which scales appropriately to the longitude and latitude of any given dataset.

`fitBounds()` meets my needs if I could add more "padding" around the region.

Looking at the help menu, this could be possible using `fitBounds(options = list()` but the link provided leads to the leaflet for Javascript help menu.

**My question is; how do I set padding in fitbounds?**

Here is some example code adapted from the leaflet tutorial;

```
library(tidyverse)
library(leaflet)

leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles() %>%
  fitBounds(
    lng1=-118.456554, lat1=34.078039,
    lng2=-118.436383, lat2=34.062717
  )
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass the `padding` option to `fitBounds()`, you have to create a list with a vector including your bounds named `padding`;

i.e. `fitbounds(options = list(padding = c(50,50)))`

In the example;

```
library(tidyverse)
library(leaflet)

leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles() %>%
  fitBounds(
    lng1=-118.456554, lat1=34.078039,
    lng2=-118.436383, lat2=34.062717,
    options = list(padding = c(400,400))
  )
```